# F# shortcut to access a property of an optional record

Tags: f#

I am looking at the F# syntax and I wonder if there is any operator to access to a struct field when the struct is optional and assign assign None to the expression the original struct was optional. For example a way to shorten the first line into the second:

```
type Post = { picture: string }
let post:Post option = None
let maybeImage = if post <> None then Some post.Value.picture else None
let maybeImage = Option.bind (fun p -> p.picture ) post
// the operator I am looking should be a shortcut for the previous operations:
let maybeImage = post?picture
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Record fields are usually accessed by compiler-generated properties, where the field name is the same as the property name. Alternatively, you might use `Record Patterns`, see [spec 7.10](https://fsharp.org/specs/language-spec/4.1/FSharpSpec-4.1-latest.pdf), to match the field name and retrieve the field's value.

Also, in monad terms, the operation you are after is `map`, not `bind`, as [Bent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60773788/)'s answer points out.

```
type Post = { picture: string }
let post = None
let maybeImage = Option.map (fun { picture = p } -> p)
// val maybeImage : (Post option -> string option)
maybeImage post
// val it : string option = None
```

---

While `bind` has a canonical operator [`>>=`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_(functional_programming)#Overview), `map` is often considered a [functor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_(functional_programming)#Derivation_from_functors). As such, you can replace it with functional composition `>> map`, here `>> Option.map`.

Generally, it is not recommended, but by using Reflection it's actually quite possible and in some situations even very useful to define a custom operator that combines the record accessor and the `map` operation. It's a generic operator that takes the field name as a string and would work on any record, but must be given enough type information being able to figure out the result type.

```
open Microsoft.FSharp.Reflection
let (?) (o : 'T option) name : 'R option =
    typeof<'T>.GetProperty name |> function
    | null -> None
    | pi -> Option.map (pi.GetValue >> unbox<'R>) o 
// val ( ? ) : o:'T option -> name:string -> 'R option
let pictureName : string option = post?picture
// val pictureName : string option = None
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be post?"picture"

Comment: @Asti F#'s dynamic operator expressions takes a string literal, with the translation `expr ? ident → (?) expr "ident"`.

Comment: Why is it not recommended? because of readability and documentation?

Comment: Unfortunately this option doesn't seem to work on Fable (javascript)

Answer (score 0):

```
type Post = { picture: string }

let getPostPicture (post: Post option) =
    Option.map (fun p -> p.picture) post

let post = Some { picture = "the picture" }

let picture = getPostPicture post

match picture with
| Some picture -> printfn "%s" picture
| None -> printfn "No picture."
```

You should not use Value, and not test for option values the way you did. Instead,

```
let maybeImage = match post with Some post -> Some post.picture | None -> None
```

Which can be shortened to

```
let maybeImage = Option.map (fun p -> p.picture) post
```